# is there a way to do multi threaded sqlite transactions and check for database lock state

Tags: android, multithreading, sqlite

I have an application that is doing a LOT of sqllite transactions, I currently have a bit of a hang because I am doing the sqllite actions on the UI thread... yes bad...

so I made each item have a thread and execute on it assuming sqllite api was smart enough to FIFO them.. nope ... now I get database is locked exceptions

[this says it should work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12350582/how-to-execute-threads-in-parallel-and-insert-corresponding-data-in-sqlite-datab)

without completely rewriting my code, and having a list of transactions queue up and execute them all on the same thread (many different classes, would be kind of a pain)

is there a way for me to check, and not execute a thread unless there isnt a lock? a lock check per se, or something similar that would get this to work, is efficient and isn't a huge rewrite?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer that you quoted seems to be confusing.  You don't have to do anything *special* when you are accessing the same Android database using the *same* database object with multiple threads.  Under the covers, Sqlite has it's own locking to guarantee that the database will not be corrupted.  To quote [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12350582/how-to-execute-threads-in-parallel-and-insert-corresponding-data-in-sqlite-datab);

> Sqlite under Android is single threaded. Even if multiple threads were using the same database connection, my understanding is that they would be blocked from running concurrently. There is no way to get around this limitation

It has it's own locking which serializes the requests.  This means that adding multiple threads will *not* increase the performance of the database unfortunately.

As my other answer mentions, you *cannot* use multiple database objects to the same database from multiple threads since there is no locking and you will corrupt your database.

Comment: First off, thank you for the response, and the original post :) - Secondly, the thing you have to do special is "using the same database object" and herein lies all of my troubles