# Multiple databases in android app

Tags: android, sqlite, database-design

I have a 'data viewing' app where I want the user to be able to select the database they view based on its name, in the login activity. My databases are created in sqlite and are copied into the application. However, I have a problem in selecting the database I want dynamically because my contentProvider loads at runtime, not when the database is first called. Furthermore, I don't want to have multiple database classes as I don't know how many datasets the user will be using.

My question is: is it possible to change the database my app uses from within the app itself? Do I need to load all the databases at once, and if so, is there a way to do so without knowing how many there will be now?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Meybe this link can help you. It's simmilar topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498664/android-multiple-databases-open

Comment: Thanks for the link. The problem with that solution however is that I have no way of knowing whether the user will have 1, or 3, or more databases.

Answer (score 0):

For those interested, I implemented a solution using multiple tables which I create and call programmatically using this approach: [Android: can I use one SQLiteOpenHelper class for multiple database files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234030/android-can-i-use-one-sqliteopenhelper-class-for-multiple-database-files).

It's not as elegant as having multiple databases, but at least it allows me to send across another table telling the app which tables the database has, and with an appropriate naming convention I can treat groups of tables as separate databases.