# Is it a good way to put 2 databases in android app?

Tags: android, sqlite, logic

I am working on an application in the application I need pre-populated database, and I also want our regular database too. Is there any other way to do this in only one database. Or it is good to take 2 databases.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: sure, you can use one database

Comment: but will it be maintainable in situation of app updates?  cos I want some pre-populated data too.

Comment: Rather than regular , you can go for Realm. Performance wise also the same is good. https://realm.io/news/realm-for-android/

Comment: Ok... and is it a bad way to use 2 databases in android app that I am doing one is pre populated and other one is created by app  ?

Comment: @Stallion your comment is not related to what the OP is asking.

Comment: @PradeepDeshmukh its seem possible and ok to have multiple databases in apps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234030/android-can-i-use-one-sqliteopenhelper-class-for-multiple-database-files

Comment: You can do it several ways. Do you plan to use ORM (GreenDao or something else)? Are regular tables structure the same as pre-populated?  Is user allowed to modify pre-populated data ?

Comment: @MuhammadBabar and Pradeep Deshmukh , If you can go through Realm features, its obvious that two DB's is possible in one App.